# What is a universal sentence?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Is it just a sentence that starts with a universal quantifier? If so, isn't every sentence A equivalent to the sentence

$$\forall x A$$

Where x does not appear in A?

Comment: It's not necessarily equivalent, if it's possible for a model to be empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A universal sentence is a sentence of the form
$$\forall x_1\forall x_2\cdots\forall x_n A$$
where $A$ is a **quantifier-free** formula.

A first-order sentence $\sigma$ is logically equivalent to a universal sentence if and only if every substructure of a model of $\sigma$ is a model of $\sigma;$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195216/equivalence-to-a-universal-formula)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you draw that conclusion, but as long as you are not dealing with *free logics* (where the domain can be empty, and hence every universal is automatically true, regardless of the truth of $A$), the equivalence does indeed hold.

Most logics assume the assumption of Existential Import, which is the assumption that any domain we consider is non-empty, and with that Assumption $\forall x A$ is equivalent to just $A$. Indeed, we typically agree to the following equivalence principle:

**Null Quantification**

where $A$ is a formula that does not contain $x$ as a free variable:

$\forall x A \Leftrightarrow A$

$\exists x A \Leftrightarrow A$