# When we say two fields are isomorphic, does that just mean they are isomophic as rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If we say fields $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic, does that just mean they are isomorphic as rings, or is there something else?

Comment: A field homomorphism is a ring homomorphism between fields - so yes!

Comment: Please see [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035639/when-we-say-two-fields-are-isomorphic-does-that-just-mean-they-are-isomophic-as#comment6261180_3035670), which explains just what TonyK's answer means by "field structure".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In a sense, yes, that is what it means. But not really. When we say two structures $S$ and $T$ of a certain type are isomorphic, we mean that there is a bijection $\varphi:S\rightarrow T$ which preserves the structure. So, for instance, if $\circ$ is a binary operation in the structure, then for $x,y\in S$, we have $\varphi(x\circ y)=\varphi(x)\circ \varphi(y)$.

It turns out that preserving the ring structure is enough to preserve the field structure; a field is just a commutative ring with inverses, so the property of being a field is preserved if the operations $+$ and $\times$ are preserved. Thus two fields are isomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic when considered as rings. But this is a contingent fact, and it's not really what we *mean* when we say that two fields are isomorphic.

I realise that this view verges on philosophy, and I wouldn't defend it to the death. I am just trying to give an idea of what mathematicians are thinking of when they say *isomorphic*.

Comment: So in other words, you would want the field isomorphism to include a condition like: if $x \ne 0$ then $\phi(x) \ne 0$ and $(\phi(x))^{-1} = \phi(x^{-1})$, right?  (Or possibly, if $x \ne 0$ *and* $\phi(x) \ne 0$ *then* $(\phi(x))^{-1} = \phi(x^{-1})$.)

Comment: @Daniel: all that follows from the elementary ring operations (don't forget that $\varphi$ is a bijection).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this answer. There is no such thing as a "field structure": a ring is a set with additional structure, and a field is a ring with the additional *property* that the multiplication operation is invertible away from zero. From this perspective, it's automatic that a homomorphism of fields is just a homomorphism of rings.

Comment: @hunter I think some might call that “property” a “unary operation with a special compatibility condition with multiplication” so that it is sort of a structure.

Comment: @hunter: The fact that multiplicative inverse is definable over the field axioms implies that we can extend the language with a function-symbol $i$ for it and simply have the axiom $\forall x ( x ≠ 0 ⇒ x·i(x) = 1 )$. There is a good reason for thinking of fields this way rather than the normal way, because now the axioms are all universal. Not only is it intuitively how mathematicians view fields, this universal axiomatization has some better model-theoretic properties. For what it's worth, I have never thought of a field as a ring with an additional property, even though it is true!

Comment: (Of course, we need to do the same with additive inverse to eliminate all the existentials.)

Comment: @user21820 But the field axioms are *not* universal, you have an implication $x\ne0$ in it — and so fields do not form a variety in the sense of universal algebra.

Comment: @Joker_vD: I'm using "universal sentence" as defined in standard logic texts (e.g. Rautenberg) and [on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2341280). I didn't say we get a universal algebra, but universal theories  do have some nice properties. With the original field axioms, not every substructure (ring) of a field is a field. But with the Skolemized field axioms (and if you stipulate $i(0) = 0$), every substructure (closed under $+,-,·,i$) is a field. That is how we think of subfields too. Every universal theory has a term model. What you're referring to are universal Horn formulae.

Answer (score 15):

They are just isomorphic as rings.

A ring isomorphism already preserves both operations of the field, and it's trivial to prove that a ring isomorphism "preserves inverses," so there's nothing else you could ask of an isomorphism between fields that isn't already there.